# How to deal with the error "render(Object...) in Controller cannot to be applied to ()"

Tags: render, playframework-1.x

I'm using Intellij to edit a play1 project. The project is build by command `play new helloworld` and `play idealize helloworld`

```
public class Application extends Controller {
  public static void index() {
    render();
  }
}
```

Everything is OK except this error

`render(Object...) in Controller cannot to be applied to ()`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Done!

`File->Project Structure->Project->Project Language Level`

Set it to an appropriate level, I set it to 9 and the problem is settled down :)